# Spring data jdbc: how to use Point from org.springframework.data.geo package

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I have an entity

```
public class Arena {
    @Id
    private final Long id;
    @Embedded(onEmpty = Embedded.OnEmpty.USE_NULL)
    final Point location;
}
```

Point comes from **org.springframework.data.geo** package

and Postgres schema to it

```
CREATE TABLE arena
(
    id                 SERIAL                       NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT arena_pk
            PRIMARY KEY,
    location           POINT
);
```

when I'm trying to use the entity via spring data jdbc repository (**arenaRepository.findAll()**)

```
public interface ArenaRepository extends CrudRepository<Arena, Long> {
}
```

I get an error

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT arena.id AS id,
>   arena.y AS y, arena.x AS x FROM arena]; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column arena.y does not
>   exist

I see that SQL does not match schema.
But is it possible to work with 'geo' classes via Spring Data Jdbc?

I tried introduce location as List and it works. Is it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

You may annotate the field containing the `org.springframework.data.geo.Point` with `@Embedded`.
This will map it to two columns `x` and `y`.

I currently don't see a way to map it to a Postgres `Point` column.
There certainly isn't any special support for that.

Comment: I guess the same is true for the MySQL Point?